# Support for JRE-9 on SQUIRREL JDBC client

Tags: jdbc, java-9, squirrel-sql

Does anyone know when SQuirreL the JDBC Client will support java-9?

At the moment I get an error that the version is not supported, It fails while testing the java version on the start-up script.

Does anyone know when a release for 9 will be out?

Comment: their mailing list is probably a better place to ask

Answer (score 2):

I commented out the version check within the `squirrel-sql.bat`.

```
@rem "%LOCAL_JAVA%" -cp "%SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME%\lib\versioncheck.jar" JavaVersionChecker 1.6 1.7 1.8
@rem if ErrorLevel 1 goto ExitForWrongJavaVersion
```

Put `@rem` in front of those two lines.

Comment: This does not work. If you start squirrel this way, for some reason one cannot close the application. At least on win10. There seems to be some java API change that does not work the same on jdk-9.

Answer (score 1):

You could download the latest snapshot which has support for Java 9 but there is no support in the official release yet and if you do the workaround to get past the version check then the application can't be closed.

What I did was override the VM to version 8. In the install folder there are two files:

- squirrel-sql.bat
- squirrel-sql.sh

In the .bat file I looked for the following line and changed it to point to a Java 8 VM.

```
set "IZPACK_JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%"
```

In the .sh file I made a similar change on this line.

```
IZPACK_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1
```

Squirrel will try to startup with this IZPACK JAVA_HOME first so it overrides whatever the system JAVA_HOME is set to.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the latest SqlSquirrel and still got the message.  How I solved it was to add my current JDK version to squirrel-sql.bat, on the line where it checks versions...

"%LOCAL_JAVA%" -cp "%SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME%\lib\versioncheck.jar" JavaVersionChecker **1.8 9 10 11 12 13.0.2**

In my case, I had to add 13.0.2.